# MS Access: Why can I no longer right-click to add a hyperlink?

Tags: microsoft-access

I've been working in an MS Access system for a while now. It's a form system where users enter data, add links, contacts etc. Pretty simple.

On the form is a hyperlink field. For months I could right-click the field, and from the popup context menu select Hyperlink > Add a hyperlink (something like that). This would allow me to browse to a network location, select a folder, click okay, and have the path automatically added to the field.

Then it stopped working. It works fine for everyrone else but not me. What's stranger, if I go to another machine and login, I get the functionality back.

**Access Version: 2010**

**OS: Win 7 SP1**

**Recent updates: All required OS updates from MS**

Any ideas?

Comment: Details help; What version of Access and what OS are you using? Has there been an upgrade/update to either of those lately?

Comment: I have seen this in Access Run-time 2010, but not in the full version of Access. If the context menu is completely gone, you might want to try to repair the Office installation? If the context menu is there, can you choose `Edit`?

Comment: No - Edit is not an option on the context menu. Cut, Paste, Sort, etc still show. And I have "Add to Favourites" along with some text filters, but nothing else. Thanks for spending some time getting back to me - this is a very annoying little issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a long shot, but the only thing I can find which might fix your problem. Go to `File Tab > Options > Current Database > Ribbon and Toolbar Options` see if the `Allow Full Menus` box is checked.

If not, check it, restart access and see if it fixed the issue.

[image]

If this doesn't help, I would suggest repairing the installation of Access 2010.

Comment: Champion. Many thanks for this - I would never thought of looking for something so simple.

Answer (score 0):

Hyperlinks editing with mouse right click won’t work if you are executing your DB using a shortcut with minimized property. That is my actual nightmare